# Should initial features be added as input of meta-learner in stacking?

Tags: machine-learning, stacking

I'd like to know your opinion and reference on adding initial features (i.e. the ones used to train the weak learners) to the input of the meta learner (aside of the predictions from weak learners) when doing stacking.

Thanks

Comment: An interesting idea, but one that goes beyond stacking, AFAIK. Try it out and see if it helps!